# Force width when creating a shape in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I'm drawing a shape in Illustrator with multiple sides. I'm trying to make side of the shape 10px wide.

How can I force each side of the shape to be 10px thick? Do I have to use a 10px wide shape as a guide?

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting the sides to be *uniform*? Your sample has sloping sides, so each side *may be* 10px at one point but then narrows, or widens. In this case yes, you'd need to measure and adjust. If you want uniform sides, just draw a path and add a 10pt stroke - done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a "Path" with the Pen Tool and give it 10 px wide stroke.

Go to the Illustrator menu then Settings (or Preferences)> Units and change Stroke to pixel units.

Note- If this is not the units you want to be working in most of the time then  you can also simply type into the Stroke Panel Weight field 10 px and no matter what Units you have the Stroke set to in Preferences, your Path will receive a 10 px Stroke.

[image]

Draw your Path and then from the Stroke Panel (Window> Stroke) choose 10 px from the drop down menu (or just type in 10 px in the Stroke Weight field).

[image]

If you want a Filled Path afterward (rather than a Stroked Path) then Select your object and then go to Object> Expand and make sure the box next to Stroke is checked and click OK. This way you can clip off the corner or whatever other modifications you may want to your Shape.

Comment: This was a great reply, especially with the video. Thank you @Kyle!

Answer (score -1):

Move and rotate to the wanted places rectangles which have the wanted width. They can be longer than what's needed. It's done in the left in the next image:

[image]

In the right the wanted shape (red) is got by clicking with the pen to the wanted corner points. Snap to points and smart guides should be ON for accurate clicks. Be sure there's no snapping to a grid nor to pixels.